# How to display single data-values with ApexCharts correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, apexcharts

I am currently trying to build a barchart with ApexCharts. Everything works fine when the data-array has more than one entry. Somehow, whenever data only contains one element, the diagram messes up the width of the bar.

[Correct state with multiple entries:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Oku.png)

[Buggy state with one entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJv0R.png)

My goal is to display a single value with the same xaxis scale and the same barwitdh as the barchart displays multiple values.

I already tried using an array of timestamps for each hour as catigories-prop but this didn't work for me.

I use 'dateime' as type for my xaxis.
Data is an array that can contain 0, 1 or x entries. It is given to the Barchart-Component as data-prop.
Categories contains a the timestamp to each entry of data. Therefore it can also have 0, 1, or x values. Categories is used as the Barcharts categories-prop.

Here are my configurations (For the buggy state):

```
var options = {
  series: [
    {
      name: "Servings",
      data: [[1669082400000, 44]]
    }
  ],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: "bar",
    animations: {
      enabled: false
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      datetimeUTC: false,
      datetimeFormatter: {
        year: 'yyyy',
        month: 'MMM',
        day: 'dd',
        hour: 'HH:mm'
      }
    },
    categories: [
      1669082400000,
    ],
    min: 1669075200000,
    max: 1669161600000
  },
  tooltip: {
    intersect: false,
    shared: true
  },
  yaxis: {
    reversed: false,
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

Would be nice if somebody could help me out, I'm tripping over this one.

Comment: Here is a link to my sandbox: https://codepen.io/qwertzuio2/pen/JjZpvOj